# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I want to save the information entered in ASP.NET to the database and display it in GridView but the information that needs to be entered is dropdownlist selected.
The IDs of the elections held are kept.

`int birim =Convert.ToInt32(DDLbirim.SelectedValue);`
and

```
int birim=(int)DDLbirim.SelectedValue;
```

I write but in the form of an error. How can I help you track a way?

Comment: You shoudnt do this by that way its wrong this is the text value of the selected element and if you want to get selected index just use `DDLbirim.SelectedIndex` to get the index no need to convert selected value.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to convert a `string` to `int`.
`Convert.ToInt32` is one of them, but like `int.Parse`, it raises an exception if your `string` is not a `numeric`

To avoid the exception, you can use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

The `TryParse` method is like the `Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.

```
bool isSuccees= Int32.TryParse(DDLbirim.SelectedValue, out birim );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `DDLbirim.SelectedValue` is not a valid int so it can not cast it to a int hence the exception.

I would do an `int.TryParse` to check if the value is a valid int.

```
bool successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(DDLbirim.SelectedValue, out birim);
if (successfullyParsed){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selectedValue is *null* when the dropdown isn't selected as valid. Else, as long as each item in the dropdown have a valid value, it will return as proper

The value is of type object, as it can store any type available.

Make sure that the values being set in the designer or backend are indeed integer and not string. Good way to identify would be as

```
if (ddlBrim.SelectedIndex >=0) {
   var value = ddlBrim.SelectedValue;
   // Inspect value in debugger to validate at this point
   int intValue = -1;
   if (Int32.TryParse(ddlBrim.SelectedValue, out intValue) {
       // use the result value here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If DDLbirim.SelectedValue is null or if contains non-integer value you have to use  TyrParse. TryParse handles nulls and invalid strings

int birim=0;
if (int.TryParse(DDLbirim.SelectedValue, out birim)){

}

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you correctly bind the dropdownlist i.e. with displayMember, ValueMember (field must be parsable to the integer value), and Datasource.

Once it's fine, you can try to parse it.